# JPA Persist method

Tags: mysql, jpa

How to insert the data to a table using JPA with hibernate only for certain columns of the table?
For example, in employee table, I want to insert only the primary key and rest all should be empty. How should I write query using JPA?

Answer (score 1):

You must first verify that all fields are nullable.

Second you have to have modeled the JPA entity that represents the table.

Third you have to have injected an entityManager and invoke the persist () method.

The code would look something like this:

Service:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
// if you annotate the id as autogenerated or sequence, 
// you shouldn't set the id property, if it's manual you should do 
// emp.setId (1)
```

DAO:

```
entityManager.persist(emp)
```